# How to copy cells in a row with varying lengths using VBA

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I'm trying to copy cells in a row but every row will have varying lengths.
Eg: Row1 has data from A1:H1
    Row2 has data from A2:L2
    Row3 has data from A3:D3
The usual code would be .Range(.Cells(i,"A"),.Cells(i,"H")).Copy
But in a loop how do I make this detect the length of the row??

Thanks!

Comment: "Length of a row"?  Do you mean the last column, to the right?  To get the last cell with data, in a row (let's use row 5, for example), you can do `lastCol = Cells(5,Columns.Count).End(XlToLeft).Column`, which gives you the last column. Then, it's just `myRowRange = Range(Cells(5,1),Cells(5,lastCol))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyRows
    Dim intCounter as Integer
    For intCounter = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(intcounter,1), Cells(intcounter,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy
        ' Copy your stuff, where you want
    Next intCounter
End sub
```

And in your specific case:

```
.Range(.Cells(i,1),.Cells(i,.Cells(i,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy
```

Comment: The row i'm copying is already in a loop. Please have a look at the code below
`For j = 1 To lastrow2
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B").Value = bidtype Then

        .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "L")).Copy`

Comment: @adr0327 I'll add the custom code, but the code above works and some little manipulating on your side wouldn't kill anybody

Comment: One more question please.. I have a cell copied from one sheet and would like to paste the cell in another sheet over a range of cells in a column for example 10. Its the next step to the above asked doubt. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. What is the problem? Do you need helpt pasting in another sheet? Do you want to transpose your clipboard? I might be able to help, but you need to explain a little more

Comment: If you see the Cells(j,"A").Copy line. It's just one cell, but I would like to paste it until the end of the column as in "C" column. Doable?
For j = 1 To lastrow2
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B").Value = bidtype Then
        rWs.Range(rWs.Cells(j, 3), rWs.Cells(j, rWs.Cells(j, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy
         tWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        rWs.Cells(j, "A").Copy
         tWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    End If
Next j

Comment: Sorry but your code in the comment is a mess and I can't even begin to decipher it. Is your problem copying **one** cell into a **multiple cell** range? That should be doable see this `Cells("A1").Copy Range("B2:B5")`

Comment: I added the code in the answer below. Please have a look. Appreciate you help man!